# Use of convertmodis_gdal.convertModisGDAL

Tags: python, remote-sensing, modis, pymodis

I tried to get ET and PET layer for MOD16A2 by using `convertmodis_gdal.convertModisGDAL`:

```
modisconv = convertmodis_gdal.convertModisGDAL(hdf, output, "(1 0 0)", 500, outformat='GTiff', epsg=32647, wkt=None, resampl='NEAREST_NEIGHBOR', vrt=False)

modisconv = convertmodis_gdal.convertModisGDAL(hdf, output, '(0 0 1)', 500, outformat='GTiff', epsg=32647, wkt=None, resampl='NEAREST_NEIGHBOR', vrt=False)
```

The result is the same, is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the layer number for each band, not just 0 or 1. The ET layer is band 1 and the PET layer is band 2, so you need to use ‘(1 0 0)’ for ET and ‘(0 1 0)’ for PET. Also, you don’t need to use quotes around the subset parameter, just use parentheses. Like this:

```
modisconv = convertmodis_gdal.convertModisGDAL(hdf, output, (1 0 0), 500, outformat=‘GTiff’, epsg=32647, wkt=None, resampl=‘NEAREST_NEIGHBOR’, vrt=False)

modisconv = convertmodis_gdal.convertModisGDAL(hdf, output, (0 1 0), 500, outformat=‘GTiff’, epsg=32647, wkt=None, resampl=‘NEAREST_NEIGHBOR’, vrt=False)
```

That should give you the correct output.

Comment: I already tried your suggestion but I still get the same output, and in case "you don’t need to use quotes around the subset parameter"  i got an error when i do it

Comment: anyway thank you for helping me